# PHP filesize() works on all but one file, gives stat failed error

Tags: php, mp3, filesize

I'm writing a PHP page that generates a podcast feed by scraping an existing HTML page. Everything works great, but one of my mp3 files gives a "filesize(): stat failed" error. As best as I can tell, the file isn't corrupted, and it plays perfectly fine. I've also reuploaded the file to the server. It falls in the middle range of all the file sizes, so I don't think the file is too large. Because every other file returns a file size, I'm assuming the problem is with the mp3 file, not with my server configuration. Is there something else I should be checking?

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
$i = 1; //skipping header row on table
do {
    $tr = $table->find('tr', $i);

    $date = $tr->find('div', 0)->plaintext;
    $datetime = new DateTime($date);
    $speaker = $tr->find('div', 1)->plaintext;
    $title = $tr->find('div', 2)->plaintext;
    $url = $tr->find('div', 3)->find('a', 0)->href;
    $fullurl = "http://domain.org/resources/".$url;
    $filesize = filesize($url); //<---works on every file except one

    echo "<item><title>".$title."</title>\n";
    echo "<description>".$title." - ".$datetime->format('D, M jS, Y')." - ".$speaker."</description>\n";
    echo "<itunes:author>".$speaker."</itunes:author>\n";
    echo "<enclosure url=\"".$fullurl."\" length=\"".$filesize."\" type=\"audio/mpeg\"/>\n";
    echo "<guid isPermaLink=\"true\">".$fullurl."</guid>\n";
    echo "<pubDate>".$datetime->format('r')."</pubDate>\n";
    echo "<itunes:explicit>clean</itunes:explicit></item>\n\n";

    $i++;
}while ($table->find('tr', $i) != NULL);
```

As requested: (do people point out edits? This is my first question here..)

The filename is "12-20-09_AM_Podcast.mp3" which follows the naming convention of every other file, and all the files have permissions of 644. The full error code is

```
<b>Warning</b>:  filesize() [<a href='function.filesize'>function.filesize</a>]: stat failed for audio/12-20-09_AM_Podcast.mp3 in <b>/homepages/1/d106955786/htdocs/victory/resources/podcast1.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
```

Comment: Does the file name contain any non-ASCII characters or special characters ()[]? Plus, when stat fails, isn't there usually an error code?

Comment: Seeing as it's a simple function call failing, you'd have to show the actual filename (possibly the permissions on the file too)

Comment: Check that your webserver has sufficient privileges to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason the web-server on `domain.org` isn't returning a `Content-Length` header field, which is causing [`filesize()`](http://php.net/filesize) to fail.

If the file is stored locally, [`filesize()`](http://php.net/filesize) the local copy of the file instead. If not, you cannot fix this issue as it is a problem on `domain.org`'s web-server. You could work around the issue by downloading the file locally and checking [`filesize()`](http://php.net/filesize) then, but this will slow down your page majorly.

If the file is stored locally, check your file name or your anchor again. You might have misspelled one (or both) and Apache `mod_speling` is fixing it for you.

Comment: I actually am working with the local file (all files are local, including the file that I'm scraping). The $fullurl syntax is just used for the RSS feed. Because the rest of the files work, would I be correct in assuming that it wouldn't be a server issue?

Comment: Correct. See if `file_exists` returns true. Might be a file casing issue which isn't affecting Apache because of `mod_speling`.

Comment: That's it. Turns out the file was named "12-20-09_AM_Podacst.mp3" (note the swapped 'a' and 'c' in "podcast"), but mod_spelling was fixing all the links to it.

Man. I must have looked at that file name 100 times without noticing that. Thanks!