# php get the KB size of an image

Tags: php, filesize, getimagesize

i've been googleing but all i get is getimagesize and filesize.
getimagesize dosent get the KB size just width and height which is not what im looking for.
filesize give me the message ***Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for***
the file in question is 51kb .jpg file

```
$imgsize=filesize("http://localhost/projects/site/schwe/user/1/1.jpg");
```

does not work,

how do i accomplish this?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Maybe see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203679/php-filesize-works-on-all-but-one-file-gives-stat-failed-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get file size of remote elements, either give a relative path on your system OR do a `file_get_contents()` to get contents first
. Thus, instead of http:// ,  do a `filesize('/path/to/local/system')` . Make sure its readable by php process

Comment: yeah, true, i just noticed, thanks. i should have thought of it before hand, im such an idiot.

Comment: What about a tip in [`filesize()` docs on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)? It says: "As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which wrappers support stat() family of functionality". Seems, you **can** use `filesize()` remote elements. You only have to have your server and PHP parser configured properly (security matters).

Answer (score 5):

You can't look up the filesize of a remote file like that.  It is meant for looking at the filesize of local files.

For instance...

```
$imgsize = filesize( '/home/projects/site/1.jpg' );
```

Comment: See my comment to Stewie's answer. You **can** use files size for a remote file, if only your environment and server are correctly configured.

Answer (score 1):

`filesize()` is the function to use.  It might be failing because

1. You're trying to get a web address & URL wrappers may not be turned on
2. That URL isn't valid.

If you're trying to run `filesize()` on a local file, reference the file system path, not some web URL.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also do something like :

```
$header = get_headers($url);
foreach ($header as $head) {
    if (preg_match('/Content-Length: /', $head)) {
        $size = substr($head, 15);                      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filesize` takes the name of the file as argument not a URL and it returns the size of the file in bytes. You can divide the return value with `1024` to get the size in KB.

Comment: See my comment to Stewie's answer. You **can** use files size for a remote file, if only your environment and server are correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which i solved like this. I don't know how optimal it is, but it works for me:

```
getimagesize("http://localhost/projects/site/schwe/user/1/1.jpg");

$file_size = $file[0]*$file[1]*$file["bits"];
```

Comment: If filesize() does not work with HTTP resources, getimagesize() will also fail. Calculating the filesize by multiplying uncompressed image properties will also lead to wrong results.